# I am trying to select an ability with key presses and cast it with left click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to let the player choose an ability by pressing different keys and then to cast it with the left click. All abilities have a shared cooldown before the next one can be cast. I am capturing which ability is chosen to have different effect with each one.

My code works before adding the logic for the left click, so if I press a key for an ability it casts that ability and starts the cooldown, but I can't figure out why the left click to cast the ability chosen doesn't work.

Here is what I have:

```
[SerializeField] private float cooldownTimer;
private float cooldown = 2f;
private int abilityChosen = 0;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    //lower cooldown every second
    cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

    //different actions on different key presses
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        abilityChosen = 1;
        Debug.Log("Q");
        CastAbility();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        abilityChosen = 2;
        Debug.Log("E");
        CastAbility();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        abilityChosen = 3;
        Debug.Log("Left Shift");
        CastAbility();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftAlt))
    {
        abilityChosen = 4;
        Debug.Log("Left Alt");
        CastAbility();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        abilityChosen = 5;
        Debug.Log("Right Click");
        CastAbility();
    }
}

private void CastAbility()
{
    //let you cast an ability only if the cooldown is equal or lower than 0, and if you left click
    if (cooldown > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ability on cooldown");
    } 
    else if (cooldown <= 0)
    {
            Debug.Log("Ability " + abilityChosen + " Cast");
            cooldown = cooldownTimer;

    }
    
}
```

At the bottom, on the CastAbility() method I have tried these two things to only cast when there is a left click:
Option 1:

```
private void CastAbility()
{
    //let you cast an ability only if the cooldown is equal or lower than 0, and if you left click
    if (cooldown > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ability on cooldown");
    } 
    else if (cooldown <= 0 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
            Debug.Log("Ability " + abilityChosen + " Cast");
            cooldown = cooldownTimer;
    }
    
}
```

Option 2:

```
private void CastAbility()
{
    //let you cast an ability only if the cooldown is equal or lower than 0, and if you left click
    if (cooldown > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Ability on cooldown");
    } 
    else if (cooldown <= 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Debug.Log("Ability " + abilityChosen + " Cast");
            cooldown = cooldownTimer;
        }
    } 
}
```

As I said, it works fine before adding the casting when clicking, so it casts immediately when a key is pressed, if it's not on cooldown. But I can't choose and then cast with this logic, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to understand how `Update()` works and how such a flow should work. Update is called every frame and checks what happened in that frame. Believe it or not, using all those KeyDown checks in Update, then checking Mouse0 separately does not guarantee what you think it does.

Also, as a minor comment: the 2 options your provided are identical, so the fact option 1 didn't work meant option 2 won't since it's identical. And vice versa.

But let's move on to fixing this.

For this to work, you'll need a separate ability class that would normally be instantiated for each of the 5 abilities. Of course, you can have some local structs in your class as well. Then in your update you can set the pending ability. You chose to use an id instead of a reference, so that's fine.

`CastAbility()` should be `SelectAbility()` (or a similar name). As you are not really casting, but selecting.

Next, in Update, you need a separate call for the pending ability (something like `PendingAbility != null` or `abilityChosen != -1` (or whatever a "null" id means for the ability id in abilityChosen).

If that is set and Mouse0 then you'd call `CastAbility()` that has the actual ability code for `abilityChosen` (or my pseudo `PendingAbility`). Depending on whether you need to "remember" this or not, consider resetting the value of `abilityChosen` (or my pseudo `PendingAbility`) or not.